# Using Reflection to obtain object properties and display onto Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, properties, treeview

I have been looking for ways to best achieve this task and settled on this.

https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/view-object-properties-in-wpf-treeview/

It does seem to give me what i was hoping for but when i try to obtain the object properties of a thread, i end up getting a stackoverflow exception. So it seems that the objectNode class is instantiating itself in a recursive manner too many times and then something happens which causes a stackoverflow? I am not sure how to go about resolving this and making it work even for a class with many properties (like threads) and any help will be greatly appreciated.

The objectNode class is shown below

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Server.Host
{
    public class ObjectNode 
    {
        #region Private Properties
        private string _name;
        private object _value;
        private Type _type;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public ObjectNode(object value) 
        {
            ParseObjectTree("root", value, value.GetType());
        }

        public ObjectNode(string name, object value)
        {
            ParseObjectTree(name, value, value.GetType());
        }

        public ObjectNode(object value, Type t)
        {
            ParseObjectTree("root", value, t);
        }

        public ObjectNode(string name, object value, Type t)
        {
            ParseObjectTree(name, value, t);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Properties
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }

        public object Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
        }

        public Type Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ObjectNode> Children { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private void ParseObjectTree(string name, object value, Type type)
        {
            Children = new ObservableCollection<ObjectNode>();

            _type = type;
            _name = name;

            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value is string && type != typeof(object))
                {
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        _value = "\"" + value + "\"";
                    }
                }
                else if (value is double || value is bool || value is int || value is float || value is long || value is decimal)
                {
                    _value = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    _value = "{" + value.ToString() + "}";
                }
            }

            PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();

            if (props.Length == 0 && type.IsClass && value is IEnumerable && !(value is string))
            {
                IEnumerable arr = value as IEnumerable;

                if (arr != null)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (object element in arr)
                    {
                        Children.Add(new ObjectNode("[" + i + "]", element, element.GetType()));
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (PropertyInfo p in props)
            {
                if (p.PropertyType.IsPublic)
                {
                    if (p.PropertyType.IsClass || p.PropertyType.IsArray || p.PropertyType.IsInterface)
                    {
                        if (p.PropertyType.IsArray)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                object v = p.GetValue(value, null);
                                IEnumerable arr = v as IEnumerable;

                                ObjectNode arrayNode = new ObjectNode(p.Name, arr.ToString(), typeof(object));

                                if (arr != null)
                                {
                                    int i = 0, k = 0;
                                    ObjectNode arrayNode2;

                                    foreach (object element in arr)
                                    {
                                        //Handle 2D arrays
                                        if (element is IEnumerable && !(element is string))
                                        {
                                            arrayNode2 = new ObjectNode("[" + i + "]", element.ToString(), typeof(object));

                                            IEnumerable arr2 = element as IEnumerable;
                                            k = 0;

                                            foreach (object e in arr2)
                                            {
                                                arrayNode2.Children.Add(new ObjectNode("[" + k + "]", e, e.GetType()));
                                                k++;
                                            }

                                            arrayNode.Children.Add(arrayNode2);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            arrayNode.Children.Add(new ObjectNode("[" + i + "]", element, element.GetType()));
                                        }
                                        i++;
                                    }

                                }

                                Children.Add(arrayNode);
                            }
                            catch { }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            object v = p.GetValue(value, null);

                            if (v != null)
                            {
                                Children.Add(new ObjectNode(p.Name, v, p.PropertyType));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (p.PropertyType.IsValueType && !(value is string))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            object v = p.GetValue(value, null);

                            if (v != null)
                            {
                                Children.Add(new ObjectNode(p.Name, v, p.PropertyType));
                            }
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

So from this, the TreeView can be added in the WPF simply as

```
<TreeView Name="ResultTreeView" BorderThickness="0">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ObjectNode}" 
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                        <TreeViewItem>
                            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-10,0,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text=" : "/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </TreeViewItem.Header>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
```

Then in my code, I simply write

```
private Foo foo = new Foo();
ObservableCollection<ObjectNode> nodes = new ObservableCollection<ObjectNode>();
nodes.Add(new ObjectNode("result", foo));
ResultTreeView.ItemsSource = nodes;
```

Where Foo can be any class. For most things it is working fine. But if i have a thread in the class, it will throw an exception. For example just a simple

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bar = new Thread(Baz);
    }

    public Thread Bar { get; set; }

    private static void Baz()
    {
    }
}
```

The error that is thrown is 
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Once again, any advice is greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParseObjectTree method called from the constructor of ObjectNode class seems to instantiate other instances of this class recursively and endlessly. It is the reason of StackOverflowException. You need an algorithm to limit the recursion probably by counting the number of generations.

Comment: Its not endless, its just because the Thread class has many properties. So its making the system think that there's too many instantiations. How do i tell it to increase the amount that it can recursively call itself?

Comment: Thank you. You made me think about limiting the number of recursion calls and the depth of the recursion which made me see that getting the Thread class stretches a infinitely.